# Get remote data without broken with modem response

Tags: gprs, sim900

I am writing an application to deal with **SIM900 GPRS** and send/receive data to servers in **multi connection** mode (`AT+CIPMUX=1`). The problem is when I got data from server, it may get broken by modem response too, and there is no clew how to detect that or avoid that.

The normal procedure to send data (to connection 0) after everything is ready is:

```
AT+CIPSEND=0
>
GET /index.php?packet=Test HTTP/1.1 \r\n Host:...
+RECEIVE,0,137:
bla bla bla
bla bla bla
bla bla bla
```

So consider you got modem response between those blas. For example if I send `AT+CIPSEND=1` (after the first one) I got the `>` between data block after `+RECEIVE`. This is an example, I may get `X, CLOSED`, `Y, CONNECT OK`, ...

```
+RECEIVE,0,137:
bla bla bla
bla bla 1, CONNECT OK
bla bla bla bla
```

How to get data properly without broken with modem responses?

Answer (score 0):

There is command `AT+CIPTXISS` that will "Discard input AT data in TCP data mode" (from the SIM900 AT manual). The desc is not very clear for me, but as I tested it is obvious when receiving TCP data, sending any AT command will be discarded although responds such as `CONNECT OK` or `CLOSED` will be received but after or before `+RECEIVE` block thus not interrupting the data block.